# Jquery Validate Script Error

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

This is a truly embarrasssing question. I am having a validate script problem and I have no idea why. Firebug tells me jquery is loaded, validation.js is loaded, Jquery UI is loaded and all is well. The script is on a included js page and is loaded.(does the same thing if the script in on the php file or included. Jquery 1.6.4

The error I get from firebug is:
    **missing } after property list  post:{**

The } is obviously there. I can find nothing ebfore it or after that would cause this problem. The script looks picture perfect to me.

```
$(function(){             
  $("#postform").validate({
    rules: {
        title:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 200
        }
        post:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 35
        }
        category: {
            required: true
        }

        date:{
            date: true,
            required: true
        }
        author: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,   
            maxlength: 35
        }
    },          
    messages:{
        title:{
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {8} characters are necessary"),
            maxlength: jQuery.format("No more than {200} characters")
        }
        post:{
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {35} characters are necessary")
        }
        category: "Please choose a value from the dropdown",

        date: "A date is required",

        author: {
            required: "this field is required",
            maxlength: jQuery.format("No more than {36} characters"),
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {5} characters are necessary")
        }

    }
});        
});
```

I am using ajax to process the form but it seems to me validate comes first so that shouldn't matter. I know that works.

I will also say, that I had a different set up before this (add rules on each name), the form would validate but still post to the DB even with invalid fields invalid.

Any thoughts? I have been on this for 2 days. Hopefully someone has seen this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix like this example:

```
   title:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 200
    }***,***
    post:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 35
    }
```

Comment: Thats the strange part. I added the comma's all the way down to date, then it goes right back to the same original error :( when I added the comma to title as you noted, the error moved down to category.  I did remove the comma's that you removed as well

Comment: did you also added comma to the "messages" section? (title{},post{},category{})

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bunch of commas `,` exactly as follows....

```
  $("#postform").validate({
    rules: {
        title:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 200
        },
        post:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 35
        },
        category: {
            required: true
        },

        date:{
            date: true,
            required: true
        },
        author: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,   
            maxlength: 35
        }
    },          
    messages:{
        title:{
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {8} characters are necessary"),
            maxlength: jQuery.format("No more than {200} characters")
        },
        post:{
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {35} characters are necessary")
        },
        category: "Please choose a value from the dropdown",

        date: "A date is required",

        author: {
            required: "this field is required",
            maxlength: jQuery.format("No more than {36} characters"),
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {5} characters are necessary")
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks to both of you.  Sparky I hope you don't mind if I give this to alon. Both of you were correct and alon has the lower number

Comment: Now for the real funny part.  Even though there are no errors, the form does not validate, it posts through ajax and straight to the DB with empty fields.  I will figure it out.  I do notice up in the form opening tag it says "novalidate="novalidate""

Comment: @Brad, post a new question for your new validate problem.  Maybe I can help... I've been messing with this plugin all week.  BTW:  you should be selecting the "best" answer for the benefit of future readers, not by who has the lowest rep.  After all, I took the time to format your entire code block to eliminate possible confusion over where the issue lies.

Comment: Actually since I went to Jquery 1.6.3 none of my validations have worked. Localhost, on web codeigniter sites, all stopped working when they had worked before. I am totally unsure of how to phrase the question covering so many forms